# Matar un proceso cmd(y saber cual es)

Tags: cmd, batch, msdos

He desarrollado una aplicación que arranca mediante un servidor jboss, el arranque está programado en un .bat, por lo que se ejecuta en mi cmd. Debo tener paralelamente abiertas varias aplicaciones similares, por lo que perfectamente puedo tener 3 ventanas de la consola de comandos a la vez, mi problema es saber cual es cual.
Pongo captura de un ejemplo, ejecuto dos a la vez y adjunto el resultado de `TASKLIST`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Teniendo más aplicaciones pasa lo mismo,necesitaría identificarlas para crear un batch que cierre la que yo quiero. He buscado más comandos para batch de los que conocía, pero no encontré para cambiarle el nombre a la task.

Es acaso posible?

Comment: seria mas conveniente, en tu caso, crear un servicio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solucion limpia y facil seria que en el script inicial añadas la linea:

```
title Nombre_que_quieras_ventana
```

y asi desde cualquier otro cmd/script podras ejecutar esta orden para cerrar el cmd que desees :

```
taskkill /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq Nombre_que_quieras_ventana"
```

Espero haberte servido de ayuda.

un saludo.

Comment: Me ha proporcionado una manera fácil de crear un batch de cierre, muchísimas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Una forma de identificar los porcesos, sería viendo la linea de comandos, pero `tasklist` hasta dónde sé, no es capaz de mostrar esta información, sin embargo, desde hace tiempo los sistemas de Microsoft incorporan [`wmi`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation), una serie de extensiones que proveen información para el administrador del sistema. Para tu requerimiento, podrías hacer algo así:

```
wmic process where "name like 'cmd%'" get Name,commandline,processid
```

Usamos la herramienta `wmic` para consultar los procesos activos, filtrando únicamente aquellos cuyo nombre comienza con `cmd` y pedimos los datos del Nombre del proceso, línea de comandos y id del proceso.